# Subscript out of range in call function

Tags: excel, call, worksheet-function, vba

I am trying to populate a ComboBox depending on which information from a worksheet is present. This code is reused in multiple areas of the module so I wrote it out in a call function for simplicity. Unfortunately I am receiving a "subscript out of range" error on line `If Worksheets("SheetName").Range("EG4") = "Current rate" Then` . I am using the string `SheetName` to identify the correct sheet and it is catching the name properly.

Any advice as to why this error might be occurring is appreciated. Below is a copy of my code.

```
Sub FillComboBox(X As Integer)
Dim Combobox As String
Dim SheetName As String

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Combobox = "ComboBox" & CStr(X)
SheetName = "Scenario" & CStr(X)

    If Worksheets("SheetName").Range("EG4") = "Current rate" Then
        With ScenarioImport.Controls(Combobox)
        .ListIndex = 0
        End With
    ElseIf Worksheets("SheetName").Range("EG4") = "Current rate minus 1%" Then
        With ScenarioImport.Controls(Combobox)
        .ListIndex = 1
        End With
    ElseIf Worksheets("SheetName").Range("EG4") = "Current rate minus 2%" Then
        With ScenarioImport.Controls(Combobox)
        .ListIndex = 2
        End With
    ElseIf Worksheets("SheetName").Range("EG4") = "Primary rate" Then
        With ScenarioImport.Controls(Combobox)
        .ListIndex = 0
        End With
    ElseIf Worksheets("SheetName").Range("EG4") = "Secondary rate" Then
        With ScenarioImport.Controls(Combobox)
        .ListIndex = 1
        End With
    ElseIf Worksheets("SheetName").Range("EG4") = "Alternate rate" Then
        With ScenarioImport.Controls(Combobox)
        .ListIndex = 2
        End With
    ElseIf Worksheets("SheetName").Range("EG4") = "Sun Term - NA" Then
        With ScenarioImport.Controls(Combobox)
        .ListIndex = 0
        End With
    ElseIf Worksheets("SheetName").Range("EG4") = "Not applicable" Then
        With ScenarioImport.Controls(Combobox)
        .ListIndex = 0
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I had to eliminate the quotations around `"SheetName"` in order for the string to be read appropriately and call the required worksheet. Simple but frustrating mistake to figure out!